# Sucesión alícuota para un numero en C

Tags: c, algoritmos

Trato de resolver este problema:

> Leer un numero entero N y generar e imprimir la sucesión alícuota para el número: esta es la sucesión de números que resultan de la suma de los divisores propios del anterior.

Mi idea tras realizar el código, fue hacer el ciclo for para encontrar los divisores del número ingresado, tras conocer los valores sumarlos y guardarlos en N; es ahí cuando agregue el ciclo do while pensando en que lo que contenía N será la suma y pues se estará cumpliendo la condición del while, pero es ahí donde no encontré alguna condición, ya que puse N >= 1, ya que 1 siempre será el último valor de la sucesión alícuota.

```c
int N , i , j , suma = 0 ; 

printf("Ingrese un numero entero: \n");
scanf("%d",&N);

do 
{
    for(i = 1; i < N; i++)
    if(N % i == 0)
{
    suma = suma + i ;
    printf(" %d",i);
}
    N = suma;
}
while(N >= 1);
```

La pregunta específica es: ¿Cuál condición debería ser la correcta, ya que intenté varias y según yo cualquier sucesión alícuota va terminar en 1.

Gracias.

Comment: Para los que anden enfocados en la pregunta, aquí hay una explicación de lo que es la sucesión alícuota: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesión_alícuota

Comment: Si, es tal cual lo que dice ahí, es la suma de los divisores un numero, hasta que esa suma de divisores sea 0. Bueno, así entendí:)

Comment: De hecho aquí está mejor explicado. Está interesante el ejercicio:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes solucionar con dos funciones. La primera recibe un número y prueba todos los divisores. Cada vez que encuentra uno, lo agrega a la suma en progreso.

```
int sumar_divisores(int numero) {
    int suma = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
        if (numero % i == 0) {
            suma += i;
        }
    }

    return suma;
}
```

La segunda función itera la primera hasta que el nuevo valor es mayor al valor de la iteración previa. Así se detectan ciclos.

```
void alicuota(int numero) {

    printf("Alicuota %d = ", numero);
    numero = sumar_divisores(numero);
    int ultimo = numero + 1;

    while (numero < ultimo) {
        printf("%4d", numero);
        ultimo = numero;
        numero = sumar_divisores(numero);
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    alicuota(10);
}
```

produce:

```
Alicuota 10 =    8   7   1
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Gracias, por responder a mi pregunta, tras analizarlo y hacerlo con tu explicación logre dar al resultado, estoy conociendo mas sobre funciones estos días y tu código hizo que las estudiara mas detalladas, gracias.:)